# A function that generates a boolean that differs between computers, but not within the same computer. Possible?

Tags: java, random

This is kind of a weird question. I'd like to write a Java function that will either return true or false. It will ALWAYS return either true or false for the same computer, even if the program has been purged from the computer and reinstalled (that is, no state is allowed.) It will return the same value no matter where in the program it is called, what time it is, if it's a Tuesday, etc.

My second requirement is that for all of the computers in the world it there should be anywhere from a 50/50 to a 30/70 split in what the function returns. That is, at least 30% of computers need to generate the less-likely result of the function.

My third requirement (the tricky one) is that what causes the true/false split won't be obvious to users. So splitting along operating system lines isn't okay, since that's obvious.

Any thoughts?

Update: True, "same computer" doesn't have much meaning since computers are made of changeable parts. It's fine for the value to change if a piece of hardware is replaced.

Comment: You obviously have to choose something that is (effectively) immutable for a given computer. GUIDs use MAC address (guaranteed unique for a given network card) and it's rare that users actually change network cards. You can decide how to actually leverage that into a boolean in with the weighting you want.

Comment: Actually, a MAC address has no such formal guarantee. Most networks cards it's possible to change the MAC address, and while having the same MAC on an ethernet segment would be broken I'm sure you can find cases where this MAC-is-mutable is actually used in practice. The OP question isn't specific enough to determine if this is a problem.

Comment: Yes, my first comment was tongue-in-cheek. The reality is that what you are describing probably happens by accident much more often than by design. The correllary might be if we knew enough to prevent/find this as undesired behaviour, we'd have a better chance at giving you a way to do it on purpose. [C'est la vie.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C'est_la_vie)

Comment: Defining same computer is tricky. Once you've replaced the motherboard 4 times, the storage 3 times, the network cards twice, but it's still in the same case, is it the *same* computer? If not, what makes it a *different* computer, in a specific way that *any* code could measure?

Comment: [Google answers had a thread](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/122945.html) related to this.  What are you wanting this random bit for?

Comment: So, based on your edit, you've acknowledged that (1) isn't achievable. Maybe if you gave us the *problem* you're trying to solve, we could make suggestions (at the moment, you're presenting a hoped for solution, that obviously doesn't work)

Comment: He's trying to tie the software to the hardware, clearly, but a boolean makes a poor seed so it's unlikely, hopefully, thankfully, to be something like online gambling. Could be something like A/B testing but then there are far better ways of choosing targets for A or B. The "not discernable by users" bit suggests some form of security though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the most simple solution would be to just use the last digit of the mac address to return 
true or false based on if its even or odd. 
This will ensure that on the same machine it always returns the same for a machine and it will return true on half the machines in the world.

```
import java.net.*;


/**
 *
 * @author nick
 */
public class HardwareTruthGen {

   //Instance Variables 
    static InetAddress addr;
    static NetworkInterface net;
    static byte[] macAddr;
    static boolean hardware;

   static {

       try{  
        addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        net = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(addr);
        macAddr = net.getHardwareAddress();

        //If mac address ends in an even number return true otherwise return false 
        if((macAddr[(macAddr.length - 1)] % 2) == 0)
            hardware = true;
        else
            hardware = false;
      }
      catch (Exception ex){

      }
    }

   public static boolean macTrue(){ return hardware;}

 }
```

Comment: So much of the wrong, sorry. You don't need a class, it's a static calculation, but even so, you're storing instance members which are inspected at each invocation of macTrue when you could do the calculation in the initialization. I'll ignore the double import.

Comment: Fix it and I'll remove the -1 :)

Comment: You're also making the wildly inaccurate assumptions that a machine will have a single MAC address; that the MAC address will be assigned to the machine for the entire lifetime of that machine. These aren't necessarily true (as the OP acknowledged by recognizing that machines can change)

Comment: Within the bounds of the (updated) requirement the use if a MAC address seems allowable. I'm not sure if it's possible to have multiple localhost interfaces, and thus multiple MACs for :1, but I'd argue that the implementation flaws outweigh the design assumptions here. Answers are learning tools on SO and as such it's imperative to improve them through the tools we have.

Comment: @Nirma, nice try. How about having only a static boolean class member, which you lazily initialize at the first invocation of macTrue? Essentially remove all static members except 'hardware', move the static initializer into macTrue (surrounded by a synchronized block), on exception set the value to some default, to comply with requirements. The answer has merit, just needs a bit of polish :)

Comment: Is the last bit of the last byte of the MAC address of uniform distribution?

Comment: @Atreys MAC addresses are, like domain names, delegated to institutions. Prefixes are dished out and it's assumed that implementations, or hardware, will make use of the `namespace` in a way which implies each instance is unique. Beyond that there's no rules really. 3Com could get 001 prefix and then have manufacturing apply pseudo-random values to the remaining part of the address. Expecting anything beyond that is not specified in contract or reality.

Answer (score 2):

Your specification lacks specificity, particularly in the definition of `ALWAYS` and `same computer`. Everything else hinges on your assumptions of those invariants.

Lets assume `ALWAYS` means "now" and `same computer` means "current JVM process", wildly wrong but illustrates the assumptions determine the outcome of your 2nd and 3rd requirements.

Collect data on some hardware, possibly all hardware and generate a hash based on that hardware data. The hardware detected defines `same computer` and by implication requires `ALWAYS` to be "now".

`8aca8asad8ae8f8fs8sv8sdfsf8sfs8a8faa`

There, that's mine :)

Now you can map the minimum and maximum possible values for this hash, and distribute your boolean valueOf accordingly.

The 3rd requirement is security by obscurity and thus, by definition, "you're doing it wrong" ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use systems hostname or ip address and encrypt it or a seed for a randomizer.

```
int seed = InetAddress.getLocalHost().hashCode();
// or
int seed = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName().hashCode();

boolean evenRandom = new Random(seed).nextBoolean();
boolean rand_30_70 = new Random(seed).nextInt(100) > 30;
```

It should be noted that the SecurityManager can change this result or prevent the hostname being obtained. It can also prevent you obtaining a MAC address and any other low-level system information you might want to get.

Comment: Doesn't this rely on the `Random` RNG remaining invariant, and if so is that guaranteed? (Note: *not snark*. I honestly don't know if that's documented anywhere.)

Comment: Yes, it's documented in Random: "If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers. In order to guarantee this property, particular algorithms are specified for the class Random. Java implementations must use all the algorithms shown here for the class Random, for the sake of absolute portability of Java code."

Comment: Doesn't this also rely on `hashCode` returning the same value for the same host name, across JVM versions? Is that also guaranteed?

Comment: I think the value of InetAddress.getLocalHost() is mutable, though.

Comment: @jpm No mention is made if getLocalHost() is mutable but InetAddress isn't mutable from what I can see. It can be affected by a SecurityManager though, so the return value is sort of mutable.

Comment: @Damien InetAddress.hashCode doesn't document the algorithm so it's possible that differing JVM implementations could have different values for the same instance.

Comment: What I mean is, InetAddress itself can change over the lifetime of a computer (indeed during a single session), thus there is no guarantee that that return value will be the same between two calls.

Comment: @jpm Ah yes, I see. The code in the answer ought to either cache the value it got initially, to be compliant within a JVM process, or, well, fail the requirements. +1

Comment: Really, the only solutions I can see are system dependent. JNI to access system calls, or executing something like dmdecode on linux to get a mobo id . . . or something to that effect. I'm just not seeing a portable solution.

Comment: There is none, without a more specific definition of "always" and "same computer". And now SO wants to turn this into a chat :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Have a function f(a, b) where a is whether this function has been executed on this computer before, and b gives the last result on this computer (or false if a is false). Then, for correct input, you can compute f as a ? b : (boolean)random(0 or 1).

Comment: "whether this function has been executed on this computer before" requires maintaining state, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's put on our hypothectical Computer Science hat. To really be able to reproduce the desired behavior on the machine with no state, there has to be a repeatable function inherently present.  My first thought was to examine some register, and switch off of the value of the zero bit, without changing it of course.  That may not be random enough because it depends on what instructions the CPU has been executing prior to your code peeking under the covers.

The second thought was to use some inheirent value of the machine, like hostname or CPU-ID, but they can either change (hostname) or may not exist on all platforms.

That's when I noticed the 'Java' tag and realized that you might have an uphill road in front of you if you don't want to write cross-platform JRI (don't blame you) or rely on an intrinsic value of the JRE which could change when the next version comes out or they switch vendors.

You may be able to use clock-speed, even if you have to do your own timing loop and and use compliation switches to prevent the JIT compiler/JRE from optimizing the routine. That could give you a range of values to switch on.  No direct speeds; find the number of milliseconds a specific instruction takes, and switch on whether the value is odd/even.

There's more things to try but they just get more wild the longer I think on the problem.  Please update this post with an answer of what you end up using. I'd like to know how it turns out.